# .net core 3.1 localization/culture by URL - localhost/en/area?/controller/action

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've been struggling with localizing Core 3.1 but I finally did it currently with their new behavior (surprisingly their docs aren't updated for the new changes).

That being said, it seems that I cannot find a good way make culture based on URL, example : https://localhost/en/area?/controller/action

Note : I found a solution few days ago but it did not work with Identity (Identity is essential for my work)

Please I need your help.

Current setup:-

ConfigureServices

```
            services.AddLocalization();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddMvcLocalization()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
                });


            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en"),
                        new CultureInfo("ar")
                    };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
```

Configure

```
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("ar"),
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });
```

HomeController to save users choice in cookie

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure [`RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.localization.routing.routedatarequestcultureprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in `RequestLocalizationOptions`:

```cs
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    // ...

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, 
        new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { Options = options } 
    );
});
```

And if you are using controllers, configure end points to use the `{culture}` route value:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution, but still not working with Identity pages.

Comment: What is not working with identity? is it the url format? or view localization? ...etc?

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for following up

I'm getting https://localhost:44390/en/area/controller/action
But when for identity pages I get https://localhost:44390/Identity/Account/Register
I really need this

Comment: Hi @khalidSaud, For identity links you can add `asp-route-culture="en"` and it will work fine. But I saw many duplication in your code, so I suggest you follow this article re [developing multicultural web app](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061604/Developing-Multicultural-ASP-NET-Core-3-2-1-Projec) and see the [sample project](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalizationSampleCore3) and related repository on github [ExpressLocalization](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I got identity mvc from https://github.com/aspnet/Identity and the solution works for me now, I couldn't configure LoginPath and AccessDeniedPath correctly but I used Sessions as a work around, now I have .net core 3.1.1 with fully working URL based localization with Identity MVC, I will still need to clean my code duplication as you advised.

https://github.com/KhalidSaud/Localization-Core-3.1.1


I appreciated your time again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

**ConfigureServices**:

```
 List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>() {

            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("ar"),
    };


        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ar");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };

        });
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConstraintMap.Add("lang", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
        });

services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix));
```

**LanguageRouteConstraint**:

```
 public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Configure**

```
   app.UseRequestLocalization();
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "area/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LocalizedDefault",
                template: "{lang:lang=ar}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{*catchall}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage" });
        });
```

**Controller**:

```
 [Route("{lang}/[controller]")]
 [Route("[controller]")]
```

Referenced from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-simple-localization-and-language-based). I hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer,

I followed the 2nd refrence, I manage to make it working as expected, but I'm facing 2 issues now.

Comment: 1- Starting from Controllers/HomeController, when I go to Areas/Controllers/TestController then navigation menu will get broken will not send me back to Controller/HomeController. 2- The bigger issue i have is, this solution doesn't work with Identity pages, i still get https://localhost/Identity/Account/Register but I want it to be https://localhost/en/Identity/Account/Register

Comment: You can check it here https://github.com/KhalidSaud/Localization-Core-3.1/commit/855370c393a5b36f9a9672a46346525ef3f39616?diff=unified